# Django doesn't update static files, clearing browser cache doesn't work

Tags: python, reactjs, django

I stumbled into a problem with my Django & React app.

I am changing the look of a component and Django doesn't update it when I refresh, I tried force refreshing and clearing the browser cache, didn't work. Tried giving the URL a random timestamp so it would always be different.

To be sure that it's not my browser I accessed the site from my phone and the updated content wasn't there so it's definitely NOT the browsers fault.
As a final check I used my other machine and fresh install of everything related and copied my project there and the changes finally showed.

What could be the cause of the problem on my main machine? Does django itself store some cached older version and use that instead?
[Network resources coming in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7elL.png)

Comment: is this the right way to write it using django? 

<script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}?rand=23423423"></script>

If so it doesn't change anything

Comment: Yes. In future you may upgrade this to some versioning system. Like picking script version number from env var or some config file and passing it to templates.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried attaching a version string query to your URLs. an example would be

```
company.com/static/css/index.css?version=1.0.0
```

Comment: Yes, specifically I tried giving the url a timestamp so it would always be different but it didn't work. I tried what you wrote just now and still no changes.

Comment: Could you inspect your network tab on the chrome developer tools to see what resources are coming in.

Comment: Sure I edited the image in the original post